# the memory described by local_iov is outside the caller's accessible address space

Tags: c++, linux, memory

im on linux and im trying to read a piece of memory in a remote process from my local process, the local process is being ran as root but when i call provess_vm_readv i get an EFAULT error code which means:

the memory described by local_iov is outside the caller's accessible address space.

does this mean that i do not have the rights to access the remote process memory ? the address is not stored in local_iov so it can't be that. the source code im trying to update and compile is this one:

https://github.com/thisgamesux/linux-csgo-external